# Different header for each category

Tags: categories, templates, headers

I'm working on a project where each category should have a custom header page.
Any suggestions? I'm just looking for some direction on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Any progress? Was one of the answers helpful? Do you still miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `is_category()` condtional statement

```
if(is_category('category-a-slug')){
    get_header('a');
}elseif(is_category('category-b-slug')){
    get_header('b');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the [plugin Taxonomy Images](http://wordpress.mfields.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/). In your `header.php` check if you are in a [category archive](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) and if an image exists for that category. Then use that instead of the default image.

Comment: I hv 5 category and 5 header.php..each category should hv a different header...i.e.

category A with header_a.php
Category B with header_b.php
any suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom templates for different categories. When displaying a category archive, WordPress will check for these files in order:

1. `category-{slug}.php`
2. `category-{id}.php`
3. `category.php`
4. `archive.php`
5. `index.php`

[Read more at the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display)

---

If you prefer to use the one `category.php` template, we can load custom `header.php` files based on the category's ID. Replace the call to `get_header()` in `category.php` with the following code:

```
global $wp_query;
get_header( 'category-' . get_query_var('cat') );
```

WordPress will then look for `header-category-{category_id}.php` and load that file if found. Otherwise, `header.php` will be loaded as normal.